# how to avoid 14mm hex tool getting stuck in the fastening bolt when installing crank?

Tags: crankset, stuck

As I am trying to install the eewings mountain crank as per the instructions, and fasten the bolt to 52nm, the 14mm hex tool gets stuck in the fastening bolt when I apply pressure.
I am afraid to further apply more pressure so it will not mess up the threads on the bolt, or I would not be able to take it out. I did apply a layer of supplied (along with the crank) ti-prep on the fastening bolt threads. Do you have any suggestions please? At the moment I pulled it out with my pliers, but have not gone all the way to 52nm.  I am using the parktool torque wrench along with adapter to 14mm hex tool, while the bike is on the bike stand. Thank you. [image]

Comment: Does the 14mm bit not free itself once enough force is applied in the opposite direction to unbind the bit. You’ll lose a tiny amount of tightness but at 52Nm it’s not going to matter.

Comment: Yeah I had expected that, but unfortunately when I apply force on the opposite direction, it stays stuck in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the hex bit is simply stuck in hex-shaped recess in the bolt after tightening, then I'd simply lightly tap it on the side back and forth with a hammer to loosen it and then pull it out, whilst wiggling it side-to-side, by hand. It is quite normal for these sorts of things to get jammed in the bolts such that it is hard to remove just pulling by hand.

However, it is an expensive bit of kit and a large amount of torque, so make sure you are confident that the assembly is correct before applying force. I'd suggest trying to get the first few turns of the bolt done by hand to confirm thread is fully engaged before getting your big wrench out.

Comment: Thank you, yes that is what I did at first, by hand. Felt like the thread was fully engaged. Hopefully it is just the case you mentioned where it is simply stuck inside and it is okay to "manipulate" its way out of it by tapping it/ etc. But weird that applying torque to the opposite direction did not do the job.

Comment: @yuvalon Well, what happens is that the hex profile of the bolt or the screw bit gives in a little bit, so that the hex profiles of the bolt and the bit are no longer aligned. This puts a large squeezing force onto the hex bit, which clamps the bit into the bolt. You need to make the bit move despite the clamping force and without turning the bolt backwards. And that's what a bit of love from a hammer is good for.